# socks proxy authentication in c

Tags: c, sockets, packet, socks

I have a function designed to make a socks handshake packet; but I can't find any information regarding how the authorization fields are filled. How is the authentication packet formatted?

```
void socks_auth(int sd, char *buffer) {
    char *ptrBuff;
    ptrBuff = buffer;
    *(ptrBuff++) = SOCKS_V;
    *(ptrBuff++) = 2;
    *(ptrBuff++) = 0x00;
    *(ptrBuff++) = 0x02;
    send(sd, ptrBuff, ptrBuff - buffer, 0);
    recv(sd, buffer, 2, 0);
    if (buffer[1] == 0xFF) write(STDOUT_FILENO, "not supported\n", 14);
    if (buffer[1] == 0x02) {

    };
}
```

Comment: Authentication and secure data transfer is done on the app level, and what you fill is a transport layer. Check SSL/TLS. It should be quite easy to implement what you need using OpenSSL

Comment: @Elalfer I think this question is about the client authenticating itself to a SOCKS proxy, in order to be allowed to use the proxy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest you start with [RFC1928](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1928.txt), *SOCKS Protocol Version 5* and possibly [RFC1961](http://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1961.txt) *GSS-API Authentication Method for SOCKS Version 5*.

If neither of those help, perhaps looking at the source of [socat](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/), which can act as a SOCKS5 proxy, will help.